# Accelerate Framework VimageConversion library values Planar8, PlanarF, ARGB8888, ARGBFFFF, RGBA8888, and RGBAFFFF --?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, accelerate-framework

H all,

Am new to Image processing and i need to some image processing using iphone4. Iphone 4 supported only   `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange/kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange/kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarfullRange`   .

but i need YUV420,rgb24 and some other .i planned to convert using **Accelerate Framework VimageConversion library**. but framework did all processing using   `Planar8, PlanarF, ARGB8888, ARGBFFFF, RGBA8888, and RGBAFFFF` Format . how can i link this format with Iphone's supported format. i couldn't get any explaination about  `Planar8, PlanarF, ARGB8888, ARGBFFFF, RGBA8888, and RGBAFFFF` format .

Any one could me Explain about  Planar8, PlanarF, ARGB8888, ARGBFFFF, RGBA8888, and RGBAFFFF  --?

Comment: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange is YUV420?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first part means:

```
Planar ==> Monochrome (Gray)
ARGB ==> Alpha (transparency), Red, Green, Blue
RGBA ==> Red, Green, Blue, Alpha
```

And the latter part means:

```
8 ==> value in 8 bit
F ==> value in 32 bit
```

So the whole thing will mean

```
Planar8 ==> Gray scale in 8 bit
PlanarF ==> Gray scale in 32 bit
ARGB8888 ==> Alpha, Red, Green, Blue in 8 bit each (total 32 bit)
ARGBFFFF ==> Alpha, Red, Green, Blue in 32 bit each (total 128 bit)
RGBA8888 ==> Red, Green, Blue, Alpha in 8 bit each (total 32 bit)
RGBAFFFF ==> Red, Green, Blue, Alpha in 32 bit each (total 128 bit)
ARGB1555 => Alpha 1 bit, Red, Green, Blue 5 bit each (total 16 bit)
```

And note that 4 bit may be expressed by one hexadecimal digit. So 8 bit corresponds to 2 hexadecimal, and 32 bit corresponds to 8 hexadecimal digits.

Comment: +1 for Your detailed Explanation .one more small doubt Can i process using planer?if my format is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange .  Sorry the Question is Silly. Because i have  raw data which has 20YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange  .

Comment: Thanks once again  For Super explanation.Am wasting more hours for searching this.

Comment: @Asta I haven't read through, but these questions may be related to what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085474/how-to-get-the-y-component-from-cmsamplebuffer-resulted-from-the-avcapturesession, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359727/iphone-yuv-channel-orientation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205191/how-to-grab-yuv-formatted-video-from-the-camera-display-it-and-process-it.

Comment: what about ARGB1555?whether 16 bit

Comment: Yes. You're right. The total is 16 bit (1 + 5 + 5 + 5). I added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks i ll go through those links.

Comment: @sawa: In Accelerate frameWork or some other any way to convert Biplanar to planar?